# Self reference in construction

Tags: c++

I have just discovered that the following code compiles with both gcc 5.4 and the Intel compiler 18.0.2. Clang 6.0.0 just gives a warning.

```
#include <vector>

int main() {
  std::vector<double> v = v;

  return 0;
}
```

I had a bug in my code that was very similar and I am scared that those kind of code can compile. My question are:

- Is it legal C++? If yes, what is it supposed to do?
- How to catch those "bugs" at compile time?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is it legal C++? If yes, what is it supposed to do?

It's a well-formed program, but it exhibits Undefined Behaviour, because it reads an uninitialised variable. This means there are no constraints on its behaviour (it can legally do literally anything).

> How to catch those "bugs" at compile time?

Enable enough warnings and build with "treat warnings as errors." With enough warnings on, [gcc 5.4 catches it correctly](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ocWfTiw1fG80HQ5q). Note that in the case of gcc, this also requires turning optimisation on, because gcc does some analyses (such as unused variables) only when optimising.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It is still scary that this kind of code does not make my compiler scream by default.

Comment: @InsideLoop some might say that it is scary that you dont turn on all warnings and treat them as errors by default :P

Comment: @user463035818: That's what I try to do. But sometimes you inherit code that just does not compile with all warnings turned as error. And unfortunately, most software are like that.

Comment: @InsideLoop Still, you can at least *enable* all warnings; this would be caught then.

Comment: @Angew not if enabling all warnings produces 6000 warnings, most of them not dangerous

Comment: @miniBill Been there; but spent a few juniordev-weeks on code cleanup, and the project is now pretty much warning-free. It's possible, and I think also worth it.